# TaskRouter JS - Dequeue reservation and connect to Twilio Client

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have the following code that creates both a JS Twilio Client as well as a JS Twilio Worker using the JS API.

```
function setup(workerToken, capabilityToken) {
  Twilio.Device.setup(capabilityToken, {debug: true, closeProtection: true});
  const worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(workerToken);

  Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
    conn.accept();
  });

  worker.on('reservation.created', (reservation) => {    
    reservation.dequeue();
  });
}
```

According to the documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#reservation-dequeue) I should be able to just dequeue the reservation and the contact_uri on Twilio for the worker should be connected to. I was successfully able to connect to another phone number but I'm wondering how to connect to my Twilio Client given my identity is "cool.beans" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to dequeue to a worker and make a call to the Client JS you need to set the worker's `contact_uri` to the Twilio Client identity. [Twilio Client identities can only contain alphanumeric and underscore characters though](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/capability-tokens), so your example of `cool.beans` won't work.

In your case you'll need to update the Client identity to something without a `.`, like `cool_beans` for example. The `contact_uri` should then be `client:cool_beans`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I see you mentioned `contact_uri` and on the next line you mention `contact_url`, which value should I be setting? I noticed in the TaskRouter.js docs there was this doc next to reservation.dequeue()


dequeueTo: (optional) The contact URI of the Worker. A phone number or client ID. Required if the worker's attributes do not include a "contact_uri" property. When I set this value it doesn't work and I also have the "contact_uri" for the worker set on the TaskRouter dashboard

Comment: Apologies, it is `contact_uri`. When you use `dequeueTo` how do you format the client name?

Comment: So I actually set the `attributes` on the Worker to be {"languages": ["en","es"], "contact_uri": "client:cool.beans"}. Also as an aside I am wondering why the `dequeueTo` method has "optional" parameters but the function doesn't take an object so that you can call it like `dequeue({dequeueTo: "client:cool.beans"})`

Comment: That is a good point about the `dequeue` method, an object would make more sense in this situation. Is this working for you yet?

Comment: Need to try it out again but will update when I have some results

Comment: OK, let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: Finally got around to checking it out and I have a Worker with the following attributes: { "languages": ["en"], "contact_uri": "client:cool.beans"  }. Then I have my Twilio Client up as well as TaskRouter JS auto dequeuing any reservation that comes in. What ends up happening is the reservation comes in and I call `reservation.dequeue()`, which should dequeue to the client I provided on the Worker but instead it just loops forever (trying to dequeue and receiving the reservation)

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit stuck then. I'd recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and letting them know your Workspace SID and this issue of looping dequeues. They should be able to help you or get you in touch with the TaskRouter team to sort this out.

Comment: Will do. Also is there anyway to provide feedback on the usability of `reservation.dequeue()` given that the doc says the params are optional but in reality they are not and it makes for a non-ideal dev experience :)

Comment: btw there's a bug with setting "contact_uri" on the Worker because I changed it from "cool.beans" to "bob" and the dequeue worked fine

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Yeah, I'd just put that all in a ticket with support and it will get directed to the right people.

Comment: Just discovered that client identities can only contain alphanumeric and underscore characters. So the `.` in `cool.beans` would make this fail. Will update my answer.

Comment: does the frontend really need the Voice client and taskRouter js to work?

Comment: @AlfredoDaAs if you don’t want live access to incoming tasks, or are not using TaskRouter at all, then you don’t need taskrouter.js. If you’re only reacting to tasks and not making phone calls in the browser, then you don’t need the voice client. If you’re using both, then you need both. It’s up to you!

Comment: The API is so confusing, there is no where that tells how to solve a CORS error when calling update function or call a reservation function from the task router js.

Comment: @AlfredoDaAs Sorry you’re having issues. I’ve responded to the question you started. I am on holiday right now though, so you may not get swift answers. If you still have issues, I’d recommend contacting Twilio support.